# BootstrapValidator dosen't work with xpages?

Tags: xpages, bootstrapvalidator

i'm a beginner in bootstrap,i was trying to build an Xpage with the BootstrapValidator to validate an inputText but it dosen't work,below the code source,can we help me to find a solution!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
   <xp:this.resources>
   <xp:styleSheet href="/bootstrapValidator/css/bootstrap.css"></xp:styleSheet>
   <xp:styleSheet href="/bootstrapValidator/css/bootstrapValidator.css"></xp:styleSheet>
   <xp:script src="/JQueryXSnippet.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
   <xp:script src="/bootstrapValidator/js/bootstrap.min.js" clientSide="true">  </xp:script>
   <xp:script src="/bootstrapValidator/js/bootstrapValidator.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                <xp:inputText id="username" title=" username"></xp:inputText>
</div>

<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(
function() {
        $("#{id:username}" ).bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            } } });
              ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

          </xp:view>
```

Comment: Could you please check the javascript console for errors?

Comment: thanks Oliver Busse but i haven't any error when i check the java script console!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [XPages compatible jQuery selector x$](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=x-jquery-selector-for-xpages) instead of the native jQuery $ selector.

Also try using `XSP.addOnLoad()` instead of `(document).ready()`.

Furthermore, your XPages xp:inputText field called "username" has an id in the browser called something like "view:_id1:_id2:_id8:username". So it's not called "username" as stated in your fields definition for bootstrapValidator. Therefore bootstrapValidator is unable to find the field. Try adding this to your scriptBlock instead of `"username: {"`:

```
#{id:username}: {
```

Comment: Thanks Per Henrik Lausten, i changed the function and i used x$ jQuery selector for XPages insted of jquery: <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
XSP.addOnLoad( function(){
        x$("#{id:username}").bootstrapValidator                                       but it's still the same problem the  validation of the text doesn't work!

Comment: OK, next problem is most likely the reference to "username:" in the bootstrapValidator configuration. You need to add the correct client side name of the field

Comment: i'm followed this tutorial http://twitterbootstrap.org/bootstrap-form-validation/ im' not understand what do you mean by the client side name?

Comment: Your XPages xp:inputText field username has an id in the browser called something like "view:_id1:_id2:_id8:username". So it's not called "username" as stated in your fields definition for bootstrapValidator. Therefore bootstrapValidator is unable to find the field

Comment: i m tried to change the user name to "#{id:username}: " then i added the name of the form because when i folowed the code js in the tutorial "twitterbootstrap.org/bootstrap-form-validation"  the function bootstrapValidator is applied to a form with html ! i modified the name of the form with the id from the client side but it still the same problem no validation !! below the code source with the changes!

Comment: <xp:inputText id="username" title="username">
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[
XSP.addOnLoad( function(){
    x$("view:_id1").bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
          #{id:username}:{
               message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {